# Opening a modal via checkbox in vue-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I'm looking to open a modal on checkbox check in vue-bootstrap.

I have a checkbox I'm not sure if it's the right approach with this but I need it to have a v-model too.

```
 <b-form-checkbox
    id="checkbox-1"
    v-model="healthDocument"
    name="checkbox-1"
    value="accepted"
    unchecked-value="not_accepted"
  >
    Health Documents
  </b-form-checkbox>
```

and a modal

```
<div>
  <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Launch demo modal</b-button>

  <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Comment: Couple of approaches: 1) You could [v-model the modal's state](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#using-v-model-property) with the checkbox state, so when the checkbox is checked, the modal will be open. 2) You could call the [`this.$bvModal.show('modal-1')`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#using-thisbvmodalshow-and-thisbvmodalhide-instance-methods) function to show your modal from the checkbox's `change` event: `<b-form-checkbox ... @change="this.$bvModal.show('modal-1')">`.

Comment: great thanks makes sense! :)

Comment: Expanded that comment into a full answer below, with a little more explanation and a correction to the `v-model` way I suggested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two approaches that I think are equally viable here:

### 1: Call modal instance method `show(id)` from checkbox handler

I think the simplest way to do this is to call the [`this.$bvModal.show(_id_)`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#using-thisbvmodalshow-and-thisbvmodalhide-instance-methods) function to show your modal from the checkbox's `change` event:

```html
<b-form-checkbox
  id="checkbox-1"
  v-model="healthDocument"
  name="checkbox-1"
  value="accepted"
  unchecked-value="not_accepted"
  @change="$bvModal.show('modal-1')"
>
  Health Documents
</b-form-checkbox>

<div>
  <b-modal 
    id="modal-1"
    title="BootstrapVue"
  >
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

This approach means that your modal's visibility isn't synced with the checkbox state, but that it will still open when you click the checkbox. If you want the modal to open only when the checkbox goes from *un*checked to checked, then you'll need to add a conditional to the handler, so that it only fires when you're *checking* the checkbox:

```js
checkHandler(checked) {
  if (checked == 'accepted')
    this.$bvModal.show('modal-1');
},
```

### 2: Bind modal state to checkbox state

I initially suggested to use the modal's [`v-model` directive](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#using-v-model-property), but checkbox state is a little funky in that it doesn't necessarily store `true`/ `false`– it will actually store whatever value you give it as it's "checked" value. In your case, that's the string "accepted".

So instead of `v-model`, I suggest using the property that [underpins Bootstrap-Vue's modal's `v-model` directive](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#comp-ref-b-modal-v-model): `visible`.

This way, the modal will be in sync with the checkbox's checked state, so that when the checkbox is checked, the modal will be open, and when it's unchecked, the modal will be closed. This makes sense if you want the checkbox to control the modal directly.

This also means that to dismiss the modal, we'll need to programmatically uncheck the checkbox (which may or may not be desirable based on your use case). Here's the full code example:

```html
<b-form-checkbox
  id="checkbox-1"
  v-model="healthDocument"
  name="checkbox-1"
  value="accepted"
  unchecked-value="not_accepted"
>
  Health Documents
</b-form-checkbox>

<div>
  <b-modal 
    id="modal-1"
    title="BootstrapVue"
    :visible="healthDocument == 'accepted'"
    @hide="healthDocument = 'not_accepted'"
  >
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very handy i'll be using this a lot so thanks for the detailed descriptions! :D

Comment: Just one more thing, when I close the modal and then uncheck the box - the modal shows up again, any way to make it so if I uncheck the box the modal does not re appear??

Comment: I think the second bit of my first section should fix that; basically just make the call to `show()` conditionally, based on [the event](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox#comp-ref-b-form-checkbox-events) that gets passed to the handler. In other words, only call `this.$bvModal.show('modal-1')` if the checkbox is getting checked. That should stop it from opening the modal when you uncheck the box.

Comment: got it missing a ' ==  '  instead of a ' = ' at @hide!

Comment: Thanks yea I fixed it with a double ==, the modal is suppsoed to be just for info after checkbox is checked!